# Is the set of non-increasing continuous functions in $[a,b]$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

> Consider the Banach space $C[a,b]$ of real continuous functions defined in $[a,b]$ with the norm $||.||_\infty$. Given real numbers $\beta \geq \alpha$, show that the set $K$ of non-increasing functions $f$ in $C[a,b]$ so that $f(a)=\beta$ and $f(b)=\alpha$ is convex, bounded and closed.

Considering the statement above, I was able to prove the convexity and boundedness of K. But I'm quite unsure about closedness.

Given $(f_n)$ a sequence in $K$, suppose that $f_n \to f$ for some $f \in (C[a,b],||.||_\infty)$. Then $K$ is closed iff $f \in K$.

But we know that $$0=\lim_{n\to\infty} ||f_n - f|| = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|)$$

It is easy to see that $f(a)=f_n(a)=\beta$ and $f(b)=f_n(b)=\alpha$ as $n \to \infty$, but I am struggling a bit to show that $f$ is non-increasing (i.e., $f'\leq0$). Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Rather than thinking in terms of derivatives, try just using the definition of non-increasingness. Hint: you can take limits in certain inequalities.

Comment: @BrunoB, thanks! I supposed that $f(a')<f(b')$ for some interval $(a', b')$ and got a contradiction with the convergence, i.e. $|f_n - f| \geq \epsilon \geq 0$ in this interval

Comment: You can also just not do it by contradiction and take the limit in $f_n(a') - f_n(b') \geq 0$.